# Jmeter is not showing correct number of samples

Tags: jmeter

Here is my test plan configuration:

```
Number of Threads (users): 150
Ramp-up Period (in seconds): 10
Loop Count : Forever
Scheduler: 300 Seconds
```

I ran the test with the duration of 300 seconds. After loading the jtl file, The number of samples shown in summary report is 7435.

I ran another test with configuration

```
Number of Threads (users): 300
Ramp-up Period (in seconds): 10
Loop Count : Forever
Scheduler: 300 Seconds
```

but the samples count showing in summary report is 7530.

I tried to compute but I can't understand how it came up with that many sample.

If Ramp-up Period is the time taken by JMeter to create the number of threads per iteration and if the duration of the test is 300 seconds, then I should have 4500 samples only for first run and 9000 for second run. I do not know how or if Loop Count affects this.

Answer (score 2):

Please, correct me if I'm wrong. But JMeter will not execute sampler once. Samplers will be repeated forever (till scheduler reached value of 300  seconds).

Comment: You are right, in 10 seconds the 300 Threads will be up and looping forever executing what's in loop. The fact that @Mahmudul doesn't double the number of samples can be explained by server having issues to handle such load

Comment: Hi PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE, thanks for your reply but what do you mean by "double the number of samples can be explained by server having issues to handle such load"?. Thanks in advance for describing..

Comment: @MahmudulHasan You could understand it by setting the Loop count to 1(disable the scheduler). Which have to create 150*1=150 sampler for the first, and for the second 300*1=300 sampler. But the successful execution of sampler(samples, hoping only one request) depends on the resource availability. From your output we can see that the sample count isn't doubled, so it can be issue with available resources in either the server or executing machine(Jmeter running machine)